# Does ethstats.net include blocks with 0 transactions?

Tags: statistics

Does the The Ethereum network status monitor (ethstats.net) include blocks with 0 transactions? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, blocks with 0 transactions are still valid blocks, and add to the security of the chain. There would be no reason *not* to show them, given that a block with 0 transactions potentially has other important characteristics, such as uncles.

**Edit:**

Note that transactions and uncles are stored separately from one another in the main body of the block, in two different lists. Block explorers, including [ethstats.net](https://ethstats.net/) (and [etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/)), subsequently report them in two separate columns. Note also that when 0-transaction blocks are reported, they're reported with other useful attributes, such as block difficulty, block time, and network hashrate.

Comment: Hi Richard, doesn't an uncle count as a 'transaction"?  I would be grateful if you could clarify that part of your answer.